# Java or Groovy based LDAP server as alternative to ruby-ldapserver?

Tags: java, groovy, ldap

A few years ago, I wrote a small LDAP gateway that processes LDAP requests from mail clients (Apple Mail, Thunderbird, SquirrelMail, etc) by looking up the results from a relational database. It's mainly used for email address auto-completion, but can also be used by address book software (e.g. Apple AddressBook).

The current solution works fine, but is based on [ruby-ldapserver v0.3](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/ruby-ldapserver/). Now I'm looking for a lightweight Java or Groovy based alternative to ruby-ldapserver, because I feel much more at home with Java and Groovy compared to Ruby.

There are many Groovy libraries for coding LDAP clients, e.g. for authentication or lookup against an existing server. However, I haven't found anything suitable for implementing a lightweight LDAP server (ApacheDS looks too heavyweight, since I just need to receive and respond to LDAP queries).

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

embedded spring ldap server

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ldap.html#ldap-server

Comment: This seems to simply embed ApacheDS into a spring app: "Used this way, the namespace parser will create an embedded Apache Directory server and scan the classpath for any LDIF files, which it will attempt to load into the server." However, it won't make it any easier to implement my custom logic inside ApacheDS than using ApacheDS standalone.